# RMagick unable to open image when it exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I can't seem to fix this.

I have:

- Ruby 2.0.0
- RMagick 2.13.2
- Mac OS X 10.6.8

The problem I have is that I keep getting the following error while running the script:

```
.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p353@global/gems/rmagick-2.13.2/lib/RMagick.rb:1635:in `read': 
unable to open image `projects/xxx/cmyk.jpg': No such file or directory @ error/blob.c/OpenBlob/2643 (Magick::ImageMagickError)
```

This is de code:

```
project = "xxx"
image = ImageList.new("projects/#{project}/cmyk.jpg")
```

Any ideas?

Comment: have you try with absolute path

Comment: What do `File.realpath(".")` and `File.realpath("projects/#{project}/cmyk.jpg")` say (it will raise error if path does not exist, and will resolve symbolic links for you - probably the first part will show you that the file does not exist)

Comment: I received the same error and fixed it by using an absolute path. Are you able to avoid using a relative path to your image?